How to fix "this.getRandomTag is not a function (it is undefined)"?
I'm currently using React Viro to implement a 360 VR view in my application. Unfortunately, I'm facing an error where using sceneNavigator.push gives me an error saying: "this.getRandomTag is not a function (it is undefined)."
Displaying the initial scene does not produces this error but for some reason, push is not working. I followed everything in the documentations and I've also double checked everything. I'm using ViroReact 2.41.6 and React Native 0.74.3.
